# Python Exception occurred

Tags: python, debugging

I am trying to fix the following error

```
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1
```

in the following python code:

```
import sys
import random
import math
```

Then goes:

```
try:
#Sanity check

if (len(sys.argv)<4):
    print ("Ejecutar con la siguiente linea: ./validador <ruta_tareas> <ruta_empleados> <ruta_solucion>")
    sys.exit(1)

ruta_tareas=sys.argv[1]
ruta_empleados=sys.argv[2]
ruta_solucion=sys.argv[3]
habilidad_empleados=[]
sueldo_diario_empleado=[]
dedicacion_diaria_diponible_empleado=[]
esfuerzo_requerido_tarea=[]
nombres_tareas=[]
nombre_empleados=[]
costo_proyecto=0
tiempo_solucion_proyecto=0


# se sabe que son 4 lineas
archivo_tareas=open(ruta_tareas)
lineasTareas=archivo_tareas.readlines()
deadLine=lineasTareas[0]
nombres_tareas=lineasTareas[1].strip().split(" ")
esfuerzo_requerido_tarea=lineasTareas[2].strip().split(" ")

# se sabe que son 4 lineas
archivo_empleados=open(ruta_empleados)
lineasEmpleados=archivo_empleados.readlines()
nombre_empleados=lineasEmpleados[0].strip().split(" ")
dedicacion_diaria_diponible_empleado=lineasEmpleados[1].strip().split(" ")
habilidad_empleados=lineasEmpleados[2].strip().split(" ")
sueldo_diario_empleado=lineasEmpleados[3].strip().split(" ")

# se convierten a entero
dedicacion_diaria_diponible_empleado = map(int, dedicacion_diaria_diponible_empleado)
sueldo_diario_empleado = map(int, sueldo_diario_empleado)
deadLine=int(deadLine)
esfuerzo_requerido_tarea = map(int, esfuerzo_requerido_tarea)

# se convierte a float
habilidad_empleados = map(float, habilidad_empleados)   

# se levanta la solucion del archivo
matriz_solucion=[]

archivo_solucion=open(ruta_solucion)

solucion_empleados_tareas=[]
solucion_empleados=[]
solucion_tareas=[]

for line in archivo_solucion.readlines():
    empleados_tareas=line.strip().split(" ") 
    if( not (empleados_tareas[0] in nombre_empleados)):
        print ("No existe en la instancia el empleado: " + empleados_tareas[0]) 
        sys.exit(1)
    solucion_empleados.append(empleados_tareas[0])              
    for i in range(1,len(empleados_tareas)):
        if( not (empleados_tareas[i] in nombres_tareas)):
            print ("No existe en la instancia la terea: " + empleados_tareas[i])
            sys.exit(1)
        solucion_tareas.append(empleados_tareas[i])


for i in range(0,len(solucion_empleados)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(solucion_empleados)):
        if(solucion_empleados[i]==solucion_empleados[j]):
            print ("Empleado repetido: " + solucion_empleados[i])
            sys.exit(1)

for i in range(0,len(solucion_tareas)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(solucion_tareas)):
        if(solucion_tareas[i]==solucion_tareas[j]):
            print ("Tarea asignada más de una vez: " + solucion_tareas[i])
            sys.exit(1)


# todas las tareas asignadas
if(len(solucion_tareas)!=len(nombres_tareas)):
    print ("La cantidad de tareas asignadas es distinta a la cantidad de tareas de la instancia.")
    sys.exit(1)

for i in range(0,len(nombres_tareas)):
    if( not (nombres_tareas[i] in solucion_tareas)):
        print ("Tarea no asignada " + nombres_tareas[i]) 
        sys.exit(1)

costo_total=0   
archivo_solucion=open(ruta_solucion)
maximo_tiempo=0 
tiempo_en_dias=0
# se hacen los calculos con la informacion en los archivos  
for line in archivo_solucion.readlines():
    empleados_tareas=line.strip().split(" ") 
    indice_empleado = nombre_empleados.index(empleados_tareas[0])
    tiempo_en_horas=0
    for i in range(1,len(empleados_tareas)):
        indice_tarea = nombres_tareas.index(empleados_tareas[i])
        tiempo_en_horas=tiempo_en_horas+(esfuerzo_requerido_tarea[indice_tarea] / (0.5 + habilidad_empleados[indice_empleado]))
    tiempo_en_dias= int(math.ceil(tiempo_en_horas/dedicacion_diaria_diponible_empleado[indice_empleado]))
    costo_total=costo_total+sueldo_diario_empleado[indice_empleado]*tiempo_en_dias
    if(tiempo_en_dias>maximo_tiempo):
        maximo_tiempo=tiempo_en_dias

if(maximo_tiempo<=deadLine):
    # todo OK!
    print (costo_total,maximo_tiempo)
else:
    print ("No cumple con el tiempo máximo de finalización ({0} > {1}).".format(maximo_tiempo, deadLine))
    sys.exit(1)

 except IOError as error:
 print (error)
```

Every time i tried to run it i failed and can´t realize what is the mistake i made.

I run the code in Anaconda distribution and Spyder IDE. I think that maybe it's related to the error.

Any idea about how to fix the error?

Thanks

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `sys.exit` all over the place, you should consider raising exceptions e.g.

```
    if( not (empleados_tareas[i] in nombres_tareas)):
        raise Exception("No existe en la instancia la terea: " + empleados_tareas[i])
```

This will give you more details. Then you also can debug with pdb more reasily

```
python -m pdb ./validador <args>
```

will break when the exception is reached.

Answer (score 2):

This exception `SystemExit(1)` means that the code executed fine until it reached a `sys.exit(1)`.

Now, there are multiple `sys.exit(1)` in your code. To know which one the code reached you have to examine the output or maybe run the code in a debugger like `winpdb`